# is there any way to fix this without repeating of the columns code?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Please any help would be appreciated. I have an method called private void update database and the its code inside is as below. I wonder is there any way to shorten the code without repeating ?

```
    firstNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
        customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
        try {
            Utils.getInstance().update("firstName", event.getNewValue(), customer.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
    middleNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
        customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
        try {
            Utils.getInstance().update("middleName", event.getNewValue(), customer.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
    lastNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
        customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
        try {
            Utils.getInstance().update("lastName", event.getNewValue(), customer.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
```

I have the fields: first name column, middle name column, and last name column, but they are repeating inside a method.

Comment: change your data item to expose properties and get rid of edit handlers

Comment: For feedback on working code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

As far i can see the next code is used in the three updates:

```
    Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
    customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
    try {
        Utils.getInstance().update("xxxx", event.getNewValue(), customer.getId());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

It just changes the xxx by firstName, middleName or lastName.

You can create a function that is gonna be called by the three updates.

```
    firstNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        updateCustomerBy("firstName", event);
    });
    middleNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        updateCustomerBy("middleName", event);
    });
    lastNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
        updateCustomerBy("lastName", event);
    });

private void updateCustomerBy(String name, Event event){
   //I dont know the type of event, so i just put Event. You shall use the correct type
    Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
    customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
    try {
        Utils.getInstance().update(name, event.getNewValue(), customer.getId());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       firstNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
       update("firstName",event)
        });
       middleNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
 update("middleName",event) });
      lastNameColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
     update("lastName",event)});

       public void update(String column,Event event){
      
            Customer customer = event.getRowValue();
            customer.setFirstName(event.getNewValue());
            try {
                Utils.getInstance().update(column, event.getNewValue(),         customer.getId());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
```

Comment: `update` cannot see `event`, you need to pass that as a second parameter.

Comment: you will call the update method inside the method  setOnEditCommit using this.update

Comment: i see that, but the `update` method uses a variable `event` which does not exist in the method's scope. This does not compile.

Comment: This still does not compile because of `update`'s signature

Comment: "String column"

Comment: your calls to the `update` methods are still wrong...